# /tmp is not ready or not present

Tags: tmp

today i found out that Mint with LXDE had fall.
it said that 
"/tmp is not ready or not present".
how to improve it?

additional question:
how to transfer /home on separate tome?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. Please have a look at the *[What kind of questions should I ask here?](http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions)* section of the [FAQ].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `mount -o remount,rw /tmp`.